# Magento 1.9.4 with PHP 7.2

Tags: magento-1.9

i want to upgrade the PHP-Version of the Shop (**5.6 - after: 7.2**).

> 1. Is there a major patch to do that?
> 2. Is there anything to mention(for example common problems)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes magento 1.9.4 supported to php 7.2 version**

Using this [Extension](https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7)  you'll be fine with PHP 7.2 Read all the information before move to LIVE (you'll find a shell class to validate code that may be incompatible) also 
**check magento officially website screenshort** 
[image]

Comment: you can upgrade before above extension install and checking guideline of extension

Comment: so you have to install magento completly new with 1.9.4.0 and then install all your extensions and designs and skins to the new installation?

Comment: I would do the following:
1) Check the code for mayor mistakes (e.g. using mysql_)
2) Use your extension on a test-system + check + changes
3) Live

Thats right?

Comment: yes right mate.. @ChristianStegemann

Comment: I already have Version 1.9.4 so i dont need the patch?

Comment: no all patches included in version 1.9.4

Answer (score 1):

> Magento has released Patch for this [Download](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2240) and apply using SSH

**Or**

> You can [Download](https://magentary.com/kb/php-7-2-patches-for-magento-1-x-without-ssh/) and unzipp file from here according by your version